# How can I add color-mode-aware styling to <SfTextBox>es without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, blazor, tailwind-css, syncfusion

I am using Tailwind CSS and Syncfusion in my hosted Blazor WebAssembly app. I want to change the background color of input fields based on the color mode (light mode/dark mode), and I want the color to be transparent.

Can it be done? And to repeat myself; I don't want JavaScript solutions.

The rendered HTML for a `<SfTextBox>` looks like this:

```
<input id="name" autocomplete="on" type="text" 
       class="e-control e-textbox e-lib e-input" 
       name="name" role="textbox" tabindex="0" 
       aria-disabled="false" _bl_4="">
```

I have this class in my `app.css` that does change the color, but it's not color-mode-aware, and it's not transparent:

```css
.e-textbox {
    background-color:#999999 !important;
}
```

For transparency, none of these work:

```css
.e-textbox {
    /* This doesn't work */
    background-color:#99999940 !important;
}

.e-textbox {
    /* This doesn't work */
    background-color:rgba(127,127,127,.25) !important;
}

.e-textbox {
    /* This doesn't work */
    @apply bg-neutral-500 bg-opacity-25;
}
```

And for color mode awareness, this doesn't work:

```css
.e-textbox {
    /* This doesn't work */
    @apply 
        bg-neutral-900
        bg-opacity-10
        dark:bg-neutral-200 
        dark:bg-opacity-10;
}
```